# Symfony 3 - Cannot use session get user

Tags: php, symfony

I have a User entity on my project.
Each page load, I bother to recover the user with a query in the database.

My goal is to put it in session variable directly after it has logged in to simply get it back when I want.

In my code, if I test this:

```
$user = $this->checkBDD($mail,$fredurne,$nomComplet);
        dump($user);

        $this->session->set('user',$user);

        $user = $this->session->get('user');
        dump($user);
```

I have :

[image]

So, the session seems work.

Now, I put it into application. I create a function:

```
$user = $this->getUtilisateur($mail,$fredurne,$nomComplet);
dump($user);
```

With

```
public function getUtilisateur($mail,$fredurne,$nomComplet)
    {
        if(!$this->session->has('user'))
        {
            dump("user not in session");
            $user = $this->checkBDD($mail,$fredurne,$nomComplet);
            $this->session->set('user',$user);
        }

        else
        {
            dump("user in session");
            $user = $this->session->get('user');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

And I have :

[image]

So, I don't understand what's the problem

Comment: is your `UserCas` extended the Symfony `UserInterface`?

Comment: No, he doesn't :/

Comment: Do you have something if you try `dump($this->getUser());` in a Controller?

Comment: lazy loading, maybe?

Comment: My UserCas entity, no. On the other hand, for the management of the roles, it passes by another entity (managed by a bundle, which contains him well the UserInterface)

Comment: It's not easy to explain ^^' I will make a post tomorrow with more explications. But yes, when I dump $this->getUser() in a controler, it works ( but it's not really my user entity )

Comment: Why did you tag this with Symfony when you are clearly not using the Symfony framework?

Comment: We dont even know what $this->session is .... ???

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**
Doctrine entity is stored on session but needs to be refreshed
But when you retrieve the entity from session : Doctrine unit of work does not know it have to handle this entity

After that you should have some issues with Doctrine lazy loading.

Session is not good to store an entity.

**A better solution is :**

- Inject Doctrine entity manager in your service
- Only store id on session
- On `getUtilisateur` method retrieve the user with id if not already done